# how to show details of a specific id using datatable server side in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

i have houses and their details.am able to display all the houses in a datatable.i have a column in the datable whereby a user clicks and they are redirected to another page with all the house details.here is where a small bug that am unable to understand.on the details page the houses of the details are being displayed in a datatable.i want to pass the id of the house to the house details datatable function so that i can pass it to the route.i have tried this but i get a route not defined error, meaning the id isn't being passed. here is my jquery code.

// show all rental details of the house in a datatable

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var hseid=$('#house_id').val();

        var rentaldetailstable = $('#rentaldetailstable').DataTable({
        
        processing:true,
        serverside:true,
        reponsive:true,


        ajax:'{{ route("get_rentaldetails/' + hseid '") }}', //the hseid here isnt passed
        columns: [
          { data: 'id' },
          { data: 'image',
              render: function ( data, type, full, meta, row) {
                  return "<img src=\"/imagesforthewebsite/alternateimages/small/" + data + "\" height=\"80px\" height=\"80px\"/>"
              }
          }, 
          { data: 'status',name:'status',orderable:true,searchable:true },
          { data: 'delete',name:'delete',orderable:false,searchable:false },
        ],

        
      });
    });
```

Comment: That means you don't have a matching routes defined in `routes` file that too with a query parameter

Comment: True. it can not be read by jquery. you need to put the data of 'roomimgid' in a hidden input , then take it from jquery code again (select the hidden input by it's id or class in jquery code)

Comment: @MayankPandeyz the route already there..what i want to achieve is to get the id then pass it to the aax route

Comment: @AliSafaei yes i have done that and on alert am able to get the id,i want to pass the id tho the route

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are missing :

```
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
```

and inside $.ajax :

```
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {}
```

Comment: I have already include the csrf token still the same error route not defined,the id isnt being passed

Comment: are you posting it? and if you are, did you add "@csrf" inside form tag in blade?

Comment: nop the route gets data for that spefic id and the passes it t the datatable